# Firefox not downloading correct file to machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-router

I have a react application that I built that uses redux, react router v4 and d3 for visualization of data.
My app contains a force directed graph, a table and a histogram.  Each one of these views contains clickable nodes, table cell and bars that when clicked, the file should download to user's machine.  I recently updated firefox to the latest version 62.0.2 and the download no longer functions as expected, however it still works fine in Chrome.
The files sit on the same domain as the application and I've coded the download to function as so:

```
    let newlink = document.createElement('a');
    newlink.setAttribute('download', 
 'https://www.example.com/docs/xml/file1.xml');
    newlink.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.example.com/docs/xml/file1.xml');
    newlink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    document.body.appendChild(newlink);
    newlink.click();
```

What firefox is doing is downloading the index.html file at my app root rather than what is in the url variable (ex. https://www.example.com/docs/xml/file1.xml).  The dialog shows that it is in fact trying to save the file with the correct name (Firefox has automatically replaced '/' with underscores to save the file. The domain is correct, but the location does not contain the full URL to the file. Is something happening with the full URL being chopped off somehow?

The type on the dialog box is HTML (which is incorrect, all my files are either xml or txt) and if user selects save or open, it saves index.html or opens up a blank/black webpage.  I'm going crazy trying to figure out what is happening here.  Please help!

[image]

Comment: what is the MIME type returned by the server for the requested file?

Comment: The server isn't returning a file to me.  It returns a JSON object with one of the fields being the url that I in turn build the anchor tag out of.

Comment: So what ended up fixing this in Firefox was unregistering the service worker from the domain, and commenting out the register service worker function in my UI code.  For whatever reason the service worker was intercepting this and causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up fixing this in Firefox was unregistering the service worker from the application's domain by navigating to about:serviceworkers (in firefox).  I then commented out the register service worker function in my UI code because I'm not using them for this application anyway. For whatever reason the service worker was intercepting the file download and causing the browser to download the index.html file rather than the text file it was supposed to.  Once I did these two things, the file was downloaded correctly.  If anyone would know why that would be, I'd love a comment.